# file transfer from 1 remote server to another remote server without downloading file

Tags: bash, curl, sftp, file-transfer, remote-server

I am trying to write a Bash script on my server (My Server) that will grab a file from one remote server (Source) and copy it to a Dropbox account (Destination). I need to get the file from Source via SFTP and will be copying it to Destination using the Dropbox API (HTTPS). So far I can get the file with:

```
curl  -k "sftp://Source/file.txt" --user "me:mypasswd" -o "/test/file.txt" --ftp-create-dirs
```

and then copy it to Dropbox with

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer " \
    --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/path/to/file.txt\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false,\"strict_conflict\": false}" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
    --data-binary @/test/file.txt
```

I'm guessing the "right" way to do this is to pipe the file from Source directly to Destination, but I'm just not sure how to go about putting them together.

This is definitely not my area of expertise, so I don't even know where to start - nested CURL calls? If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be most appreciative.

**UPDATE**
Here's the whole `curl` command I'm running:

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
    --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/xfer/chef.txt\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false,\"strict_conflict\": false}" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
    --data-binary "$(curl  -k "http://marketing.dave0112.com/file.txt" --user "me:mypasswd")"
```

I was having issues with CURL not supporting SFTP so I changed to HTTP while i get that end sorted out. Not sure if that affects anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this line :

```
--data-binary @/test/file.txt
```

with

```
--data-binary @<(curl  -k "sftp://Source/file.txt" --user "me:mypasswd")
```

If problems, try :

```
--data-binary "$(curl  -k "sftp://Source/file.txt" --user "me:mypasswd")"
```

Comment: That creates the new file on Destination but it's empty and `curl: (23) Failed writing body` is returned. Any suggestions for getting around this?

Comment: Updated, please retry.

Comment: tis also creates an empty file with the following error message returned in the terminal: `--data-binary: command not found`

Comment: just added it to OP

Comment: uuuugh... it was the nested double quotes... changed inner quotes to single-ticks and it now works. Thanks!!